# ansi C - passing value to array

Tags: arrays, function

If you call a function like:

```
coworkers = engineers(1,0,3);
...

int engineers(unsigned char nerd, unsigned char dweeb[], unsigned char derp) {
     printf("Is this the address of dweeb[0]? 0x%x \n", dweeb);
     printf("Is this the value of dweeb[0]? %x \n", dweeb[0]);
} 

Output:
Is this the address of dweeb[0]? 0xfeedbeef
Is this the value of dweeb[0]?
```

When I pass the 0 value to dweeb[] does that become the value of dweeb[0]?

--I am the derp, have a happy Friday. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dweeb[0]` is equivalent to `*(dweeb+0)` so yes, it does become the value at `dweeb[0]`.

Note that because dweeb+0 = 0+dweeb, you can also write that as `0[dweeb]`.

---

**On a closer look,** when you pass `0` to your `engineers` function as the second argument, what happens is that the address `0x0` will be used as the location of the array `dweeb`. Dereferencing that address, as in `dweeb[0]`, is undefined behavior. The most likely result is that the program crashes. What you would *actually* see is more likely:

```
Is this the address of dweeb[0]? 0x0
Segmentation fault
```

I'm not sure what you are asking, if it's "what happens if I put `0` between the brackets in `dweep[ ]`" or "what happens if I pass `0` as the value for `dweep`"